# Как получить данные от API?

Tags: php, api

Создал кнопку на сайте, при нажатии должно в обработчике показать массив

`Array (
[Result] => ok
)`

в файле payViaPos.php у меня идет подключение к API

```
<?php
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
define('DATALIFEENGINE', 'dsdd');
require_once '../../engine/classes/mysql.php';
include('../../engine/data/dbconfig.php');
include("../../engine/api.php");
include("../vendor/utils.php");
$api=new api();
switch ($_POST['action']) {
case 'PayViaPOS':
PayViaPOS($config);
break;
default:
header('Location: /');
break;
}   
function PayViaPOS($config) {
global $api;
$url = "PayViaPOS/";
$api->post = array(
'ProductOrderId' => $_POST['ProductOrderId'],
'price'=> $_POST['price']
    );  
$data = $api->sendrequest($url);
print_r($data);
}
?>
```

в файле index.php у меня кнопка и скрипт который получает данные

```
<button type="button" class="button button--prime" id="PayViaPOS">Рассчитать</button>

 <script>
$(document).on("click", "#PayViaPOS", function() {
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: '/engine/ajax/PayViaPOS.php',
data: 
    {
action:"PayViaPOS",
ProductOrderId: <?=$_GET['productOrderId']?>,
hash: "<?php echo md5($config['salt'].$_GET['productOrderId']); ?>",
price: '<?=$order->getCalcSum()?>'
},          
});
});
</script>
```

в файле apik.php данные от api

```
/* =====================PayViaPOS =========================================== */
$url = "PayViaPOS//";
echo '<details><summary>PayViaPOS</summary>';

$api->post = array(
    'price' => '3',
    'ProductOrderId' => '111111'
);
echo '<p><pre>';
print_r($api->sendrequest($url));
echo '</pre></p></details>';
exit;
```

при нажатии на кнопку ничего не происходит, с помощью обработчика ошибки не смог даже ошибку вывести, я только изучаю api и php в целом, помогите разобраться в чем проблема

Answer (score 0):

не вполне понятно что это должно быть, тем не менее...

1. ошибка забыли кавычки тут: 
   `ProductOrderId: "<?=$_GET['productOrderId']?>",`
2. jquery подключить не забыли?

Answer (score 0):

Если работаете в хроме, посмотрите следующее: 
Ошибки в консоли браузера(вкладка 'Console').
Во вкладке 'Network' проверьте уходит ли что-то на apik.php и что уходит (вкладка 'Headers').Так же посмотрите что отвечает ваше api (вкладка 'Response').
После этого сможете сделать отладку вашего кода.

Comment: у меня показывает только PayViaPOS.php, и в вкладке `Response` показывает массив, теперь другой вопрос, если поменять данные в API, где он возвращает вместо `Ок` `Error`, то как мне вывести на экран ошибку с помощью `json_encode`? Пробовал с помощью условного оператора, но не смог вывести

Comment: В вашем js коде вешаете обработчики событий, например, обработчик success сработает в случае  удачного завершения запроса: $.ajax({
  url: '/engine/ajax/PayViaPOS.php',
  success: function(data){
    console.log(data);
  }
}); Выведет в консоль браузера ответ сервера, он будет хранится в переменной data. А, например, обработчик complete происходит в случае любого завершения запроса, как успешного, так и нет. Полученные данные вы уже используете как вам нужно.

Comment: Чтоб вывести на экран, можно вставить их в какой-нибудь тег: <div class="result"></div>. В обработчике success: $('.result').append(data);